# Kotlin coroutines multithread dispatcher and thread-safety for local variables

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's consider this simple code with coroutines

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        launch (Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10).asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
            var x = 0
            val threads = mutableSetOf<Thread>()
            for (i in 0 until 100000) {
                x++
                threads.add(Thread.currentThread())
                yield()
            }
            println("Result: $x")
            println("Threads: $threads")
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understand this is quite legit coroutines code and it actually produces expected results:

```
Result: 100000
Threads: [Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-4,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-5,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-6,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-7,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-8,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-9,5,main], Thread[pool-1-thread-10,5,main]]
```

The question is what makes these modifications of local variables thread-safe (or is it thread-safe?). I understand that this loop is actually executed sequentially but it can change the running thread on every iteration. The changes done from thread in first iteration still should be visible to the thread that picked up this loop on second iteration. Which code does guarantee this visibility? I tried to decompile this code to Java and dig around coroutines implementation with debugger but did not find a clue.

Comment: Yes, this code is legitimate, but only because you run a single coroutine here. `x` and `threads` variables aren't thread-safe, but they aren't accessed concurrently, so this is fine. I'm not sure what do you mean about the visibility of changes. As you noted, this code runs sequentially, so why changes would be not visible?

Comment: Ahh, you probably meant that `x` is not volatile?

Comment: By visibility I mean the fact of the writes to variable from one thread being visible to other thread, actually a concept used by Java Memory Model. Yes, in my opinion `x` being volatile would solve the problem related to `x` if the problem existed at all (I still assume that there is no problem with this code but it kinda contradicts my understanding of concurrency).

Comment: It seems to be exactly this question: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1363

The final answer is still a bit unclear in my opinion, I don't know for sure. But it does look like within a coroutine, the state is always "up to date", regardless of which thread modified it last. So in a sense it kinda behaves like a volatile. But I'd also be interested in an actual accurate answer for this, as to how and why this works.

Comment: ^ I meant not exactly the initial question on Github (which talks about 2 coroutines), but the discussion below which mentions the single-coroutine case

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/what-is-concurrent-access-to-mutable-state-f386e5cb8292

Comment: @IR42 This article does not really answer the question. Nobody here is saying these modifications are concurrent. They are sequential, but even then there still should be a problem with CPU caches. For some reasons such problem does not occur. Of course it makes perfect sense that Kotlin solves this automatically - otherwise it would be really hard to develop with coroutines. We just don't know how it does it exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is completely analogous to the realization that the OS can suspend a thread at any point in its execution and reschedule it to another CPU core.  That works not because the code in question is "multicore-safe", but because it is a guarantee of the environment that a single thread behaves according to its program-order semantics.

Kotlin's coroutine execution environment likewise guarantees the safety of your sequential code. You are supposed to program to this guarantee without any worry about how it is maintained.

If you want to descend into the details of "how" out of curiosity, the answer becomes "it depends". Every coroutine dispatcher can choose its own mechanism to achieve it.

As an instructive example, we can focus on the specific dispatcher you use in your posted code: JDK's `fixedThreadPoolExecutor`. You can submit arbitrary tasks to this executor, and it will execute each one of them on a single (arbitrary) thread, but many tasks submitted together will execute in parallel on different threads.

Furthermore, the executor service provides the guarantee that the code leading up to `executor.execute(task)` *happens-before* the code within the task, and the code within the task *happens-before* another thread's observing its completion (`future.get()`, `future.isCompleted()`, getting an event from the associated `CompletionService`).

Kotlin's coroutine dispatcher drives the coroutine through its lifecycle of suspension and resumption by relying on these primitives from the executor service, and thus you get the "sequential execution" guarantee for the entire coroutine. A single task submitted to the executor ends whenever the coroutine suspends, and the dispatcher submits a new task when the coroutine is ready to resume (when the user code calls `continuation.resume(result)`).